# How to get only one element from current html object using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a template

```
<table class="table" id="mans">

            <tr>

              <td><select class="form-control tag-name">

                  <option>name</option>

              </select></td>
      <td><select class="form-control tag-val">

          <option>name</option>

              </select></td>
              <td id="set-tag-name"> </td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right delete-row">
         -
        </button></td>

            </tr>

          </table>
 <button type="button"  id = "add-row" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add new
        </button>
```

I want to add only first select element on click of Add new button .

Here is my jquery code to add both select..

```
 $("#mydiv").each(function() {
  var tds = '<tr>';
  jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function() {
    var x = $(this).html();
     tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
    tds += '<td>' + x[0]+ '</td>';

  });
  tds += '</tr>';
  if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
    $('tbody', this).append(tds);
  } else {
    var getId = el.currentTarget;
    $(getId).append(tds);
  }
});
```

How do I add only first select element using jquery??

Comment: which tag do you want to select ?

Comment: I want to select '<select class="form-control tag-name">'

Comment: Do you want the entire `select` element including its `option` child elements, just the `select` or just the chosen `option`?

Answer (score 0):

U can use css selector for selecting tags in jquery like this :

```
$(".table select:first-child");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="mydiv">
<table class="table" id="mans">

            <tr>

              <td><select class="form-control tag-name">

                  <option>name</option>

              </select></td>
      <td><select class="form-control tag-val">

          <option>name</option>

              </select></td>
              <td id="set-tag-name"> </td>
              <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info pull-right delete-row">
         -
        </button></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
 <button type="button"  id = "add-row" class="btn btn-info pull-right">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add new
        </button>
</div>   



$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#add-row").click(function(){
$("#mydiv").each(function() {
  var tds = '<tr>';
  jQuery.each($('tr:last td', this), function() {
    var x = $(this).html();
     tds += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
  });
  tds += '</tr>';
  if ($('tbody', this).length > 0) {
    $('tbody', this).append(tds);
  } else {
    var getId = el.currentTarget;
    $(getId).append(tds);
  }
});
});
});
```